# Ruby - redefining instance methods not working

Tags: ruby

My simple attempt to redefine instance methods are not working

```
class File
  alias_method :old_atime, :atime
  def atime(*args)
    puts "helllllo"
    old_atime(*args)
  end
end


f = File.new("C:\\abc.txt","w")
puts f.atime
```

Any idea why?

I'm attempting to print "helllllo" everytime File#atime is called. Even `alias old_atime atime` is not working.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code  works perfectly as it should be. Puts "helllllo" writes "helllllo" in to your opened file. Puts inside the file instance meant for writing.

Just call **f.close**  and open your file in text editor. You can see the content.

Comment: Oh my! Doesn't `puts` display "helllo" in the console? What can I do to make it write to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Ramesh is right.  Try this:

```
class File
  alias_method :old_atime, :atime
  def atime(*args)
    Kernel.puts "helllllo"   # <---- Kernel method
    old_atime(*args)
  end
end


f = File.new("C:\\abc.txt","w")
puts f.atime
```

The issue is that 'puts' is defined in File for writing to files.  You want the Kernel one which is used unless defined in a more specific scope.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, but [`IO#puts`](http://rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M002170&name=puts#) writes to the `IO` object itself, *not* STDOUT. In other words, it's writing to the file.

Call `f.atime` a few times and then `f.close` within `irb` and you should see it printing `helllllo` to the file for each call to `atime`.

To print to STDOUT, you could use `$stdout.puts` or `Kernel.puts`.